# wordpress Pagination In my own page on

Tags: php, wordpress

I wrote in the root directory of a folder "360app"...Get all the articles on display here
this is my code, But shows all pages...I want to have the effect of
[1][2]..[5][6][next]

the web    www.qiqusp.com/360app

the  paged is by ?paged=id

```
$paged =!empty( $_GET['paged'] ) && ( $paged = absint( $_GET['paged'] ) ) ? $paged : 1;
if($new_query->max_num_pages>1){?>
<p class="pager">
<?php
for($i=1;$i<=$new_query->max_num_pages;$i++){?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($category_id).'?paged='.$i;?>" <?php echo ($paged==$i)? 'class="active"':'';?>><?php echo $i;?></a>
    <?php
}
if($paged!=$new_query->max_num_pages){?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($category_id).'?paged='.$i;?>">Siguiente</a>
```

Comment: rather than this , you can use pagination function.

Comment: http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/

Answer (score 1):

I think you should work with this plugin:

it must save your time and it is also so easy to use.

[Page Navigation](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/&ei=dxd6UoWmF43qrQf1wYC4DA&usg=AFQjCNEOcmEi-NQOZzMHpY-sHISbs5jkYw&bvm=bv.55980276,d.bmk)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has already done all the work for this kind of thing. Check the [Codex on Pagination](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination). You will find these functions useful.

- [wp_link_pages](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_link_pages), for single post pagination
- [paginate_links](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links), for archive navigation